# How do I get the developer tool to also inspect the popup created by a page?

Tags: javascript, html, tabs, google-chrome-devtools

So I'm inspecting how a certain page with lots of JS works by watching it in Chrome Dev Tools, and when a link is clicked on this page, a popup opens, and it closes and a new tab is opened.  I would like to see what's going on--particularly, inspect the headers of all the requests that get kicked off when the link is clicked.

However, the inspection functionality is attached only to the tab containing the link, and doesn't transfer to any new windows/tabs created due to actions in that tab.  I think there is at least one reload/redirect/spawning of a new window in between when the link is clicked and the content of the new tab is loaded, because when I attach Chrome Dev Tools to the new tab and refresh, the stuff I'm seeing doesn't jive with the javascript I'm seeing in the original tab.

I hope this makes sense...how do I snoop all of the action that's going on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Open a new tab and navigate to `chrome://net-internals/#events`. Click on `events` to get a listing of all the events being spit out. Clicking on an event below will provide more details. If it's a `URL_REQUEST` you will be able to view send and request headers.

[image]